# cannot change data type of view column SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, view, sqldatatypes

I keep getting this error

> cannot change data type of view column "percent" from integer to double precision

I have a function called `findIntl()` which returns a float

```
create or replace function findIntl(integer) returns float as $$
  select cast(count(*) as float)
  from students s
  join program_enrolments pe on (s.id = pe.student)
  where s.stype = 'intl' and pe.semester = $1;
$$ language sql;
```

and I use the returned value in a view called findPercent

```
create or replace view findPercent(semester, percent) as
  select q6(s.id), findIntl(s.id)
  from semesters s
  where s.id = id and s.term ~ 'S' and s.year >= 2004;
```

If I replace `findIntl()` with another column of values it works perfectly fine but when `findIntl()` is there it says `cannot change data type of view column "percent" from integer to double precision`

If I `cast(findIntl(s.id) as numeric(4,2)` it says

> ERROR:  cannot change data type of view column "percent" from integer to numeric(4,2)

I have read on stackoverflow about something to do with dropping tables but I don't quite understand why I must do that, and I am not even sure if it applies to this case.

Also, if I remove semester from findPercent and just keep percent there and `select findIntl(s.id)` only then it says

> ERROR:  cannot drop columns from view

I'm new to SQL so sorry for my ignorance but when I use a column of integers it works perfectly fine but when I use a function to return values why does this break and how can I fix this?

Comment: Tag the dbms used. (Product specific question.)

Comment: SQL is a language, specified by ANSI/ISO. There are different products which implement the SQL language more or less according to the ANSI spec. However, it seems like you're having a product specific problem here.

Comment: @jarlh Ah yep, I'm using postgres I believe

Answer (score 30):

I think the Postgres [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createview.html) is pretty clear on the use of replace for views:

> `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW` is similar, but if a view of the same name
>   already exists, it is replaced. The new query must generate the same
>   columns that were generated by the existing view query (that is, the
>   same column names in the same order **and with the same data types**), but
>   it may add additional columns to the end of the list. The calculations
>   giving rise to the output columns may be completely different.

You need to drop the view and re-create it.

Answer (score 8):

Views are aliases to querys. Dropping them won't affect your data, so don't worry dropping them. To work, you have to drop and create it again when you change column type in views on postgres.

```
drop view findPercent;
```

Change the findIntl function and then

```
create or replace view findPercent(semester, percent) as
select q6(s.id), findIntl(s.id)
from semesters s
where s.id = id and s.term ~ 'S' and s.year >= 2004;
```

Comment: Dropping views will not change data, but if you have nested views (view that use a view), this is a big restriction in flexibility, as dropping views must be cascaded.

Comment: Postgres documentation states that drop view command is restrict by default, not cascade. So, if any object depends on it, the command will fail and you will have to handle dependencies manually. That's better than using cascade and dropping stuff without knowing.